# Properties of the relatively bounded probability distributions on the simplex over the natural numbers

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, convex-analysis

#### Setup :

Let $S$ be the simplex over $\mathbb N$, i.e. the set of probability distribution over $\mathbb N$. Let $p\in S$ be such that $0 < p_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Let $H$ be the Hilbert space of all sequences on $\mathbb N$ with inner product defined as

\begin{align*}
\langle q, r\rangle &= \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{q_n r_n}{p_n}
\end{align*}

Note that $S=\{ q\geqq 0: \langle p,q \rangle = 1 \}$ and let $S_p=\left\{ q\in S: \exists B>0,\forall n\geq 1~\frac{q_n}{p_n} \leq B \right\}$, this is a measurable set as
\begin{align*}
S_p=\bigcup_{k\geq 1}\bigcap_{n\geq 1} \left\{ q\in S: \frac{q_n}{p_n} \leq k \right\}
\end{align*}

#### Question :

> Suppose we have a probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ that is such that for all $q\in S$, $\int_S \langle q, r\rangle~ d\mu(r) = \langle q, p\rangle$. Is it possible to prove that $\mu(S_p)=1$ ?

#### Discussion :

We can prove (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828251/can-the-set-of-sequences-such-that-fracb-na-n-is-unbounded-be-specified-b)) that for any $q\in S\setminus S_p$, there is a sequence $\{f_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n\geq 1} p_n f_n = B < \infty$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1} q_n f_n = \infty$, we can write $r_n=\frac{p_n f_n}{B}$ to get that $\langle p, r\rangle = 1$ (i.e $~r\in S$) and $\langle q, r\rangle = \infty$. There cannot be any $q$ such that $\int_S \langle q, r\rangle~ d\mu(r) \geq \int_{S\setminus S_p} \langle q, r\rangle~ d\mu(r) = \infty \neq 1 = \langle q, p\rangle$. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828251/can-the-set-of-sequences-such-that-fracb-na-n-is-unbounded-be-specified-b), I attempted to show that there is countably many $r\in S$ needed to exclude all $q\in S\setminus S_p$ with $\langle q, r\rangle =\infty$, which would be enough to prove my result. This turns out to be false, and I am left out with no track, so any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: Let $p_n=2^{-n}$, take independent random variables $X_n=1,n$ with $P(X_n=n)=1/n$ and
$$
r_n= \frac{p_nX_n}{\sum p_n X_n} .
$$
Then $Er_n\le p_n EX_n\le 2p_n$, so if we take $\mu_0$ as one half times the underlying probability measure, thought of as realized on the sample space $\{ r(X)\}$, then $\int r\, d\mu_0(r) \le p$. Finally, we can put $\mu=\mu_0+(1/2)\delta_q$, with $q=2(p-\int r\, d\mu_0)$, so that now $\int r\, d\mu(r)=p$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure.

However, by Borel-Cantelli, $X_n=n$ for infinitely many $n$ with probability one, and then $r\notin S_p$.

Comment: Very nice answer, I am still unsure about something though. Suppose we have $s\in S$, then we want $\int \langle s, r \rangle d\mu < \infty$, which happens if and only if $\int \sum_{n\geq 1}s_n X_n~d\mu_0(X) < \infty$, here I don't think we can quite exchange the sum and the integral without being careful, therefore, we want $\sum_{n\geq1}s_n X_n$ to have finite expectation whenever $\sum_n s_n<\infty$. I believe that the condition in my question is considerably stronger than the element-wise $\int r_n d\mu = p_n$, however your counter example might still work (I could not find such a $s_n$).

Comment: @P.Quinton: We have $s_n, X_n, r_n\ge 0$, so we can definitely change the order of integration/summation wherever we want with no questions asked, by Tonelli (which some people call Fubini): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions (And no, $\int \langle q, r\rangle\, d\mu =\langle q, p \rangle$ is not stronger than $\int r_n\, d\mu = p_n$, they are equivalent for the same reason in one direction and because $S$ contains the ONS $\{ e_n\}$ for the other direction.)

Comment: By the way, if we want to change the order of an integral and a *sum* (rather than a second integration) for non-negative functions, we can also do this with monotone convergence.